# date is not returning past year since new year

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

This is a crystal report formula, the date is not returning open orders from last month or past 6 months. Looking at this, i thought the `-180` would return the past 6 months. What would be nice is at this part :

```
  + YEAR(CurrentDate) * 100000 - 180
```

would like to have the past 6 months.

```
  {CROPNORD.ORDER_DATE} > ((DAY(CurrentDate)+MONTH(CurrentDate)*100 + YEAR(CurrentDate)*10000) - 180)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the DateAdd function instead.

Like this:

```
{CROPNORD.ORDER_DATE} > DateAdd(“m”, -6, CurrentDate)
```